# Failing to associate (inactive?) accounts

Tags: support, openid

I got a message in my inbox saying someone had answered a question I'd asked a long time ago on at stack2.0 site. So I click the link and it takes me to that site. But I'm not logged in. So I log in with my claimID which I used for all my stackexchange sites. It says it isn't recognised and wants to start me a new account. What's going on? I've had this a couple of times since stackexchange started doing its own openID. Normally when I go on some 2.0 site that I've not visited for a while and it asks me to log in again...

In the past, what I've done is create the new account and then flag a post to have it merged with the already existing one... But I'd like to know why this is happening and what I can do about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claimid is kind of a .. subpar .. identity provider because they support two aliased forms of their URLs. Each unique URL is a different user to us, so this is a problematic (and rare) condition.

(It's worth mentioning here that ClaimID is all but shut down, you can't create new ClaimIDs.)

I went ahead and put both forms on your account and propagated your credentials network wide.

Comment: Thanks. What should I do to migrate away from claimID? I don't know what details to put in if I try to log in with e.g. stackoverflow openID...